How to prove this simple inequality based on convexity of $e^{x}$?
Suppose $\theta > 0$ and $x>0$. I would like to show that
$$
e^{\theta(x+1)} - e^{\theta x} - \frac{ e^{\theta x}-1}{x} \geq \frac{e^{\theta x}-1}{x} - (1-e^{-\theta})
$$
Another way to put it: consider the average slopes of $e^{\theta y}$ between a) $y = x$ and $y=x+1$, b) $y = 0$ and $y=x$, and c) $y=-1$ and $y=0$. Then the difference between a) and b) is bigger than the difference between b) and c).
This should be easy to prove but I am drawing a blank.
EDIT: A clarification was requested in some (perhaps now deleted) comments. By "average slope" of a function $f(t)$ in some interval $[a,b]$, I mean $\frac{f(b) - f(a) }{ b-a } = \frac{ \int_{a}^{b} f'(t) \, dt }{ b - a}$.

For the record, here is a graphical check: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/skwrdbluhc. The inequality does seem to be true.

Ask yourself whether all convex functions have this property.

@Li-yaoXia No, they don't. For example, $e^{\theta x}$ remains convex if $\theta < 0$, but the inequality fails.

@JohnBentin, what I graphed is the logarithm of the difference and not the difference...

@Simon : Sorry, I missed that.

\begin{aligned}&e^{\theta(x+1)}-e^{\theta x}-\frac{e^{\theta x}-1}{x}\geq\frac{e^{\theta x}-1}{x}-(1-e^{-\theta})\\\Leftrightarrow& e^{\theta(x+1)}-e^{\theta x}-2\cdot\frac{e^{\theta x}-1}{x}+(1-e^{-\theta})\geq0.\end{aligned}
Let $\displaystyle f(\theta)=e^{\theta(x+1)}-e^{\theta x}-2\cdot\frac{e^{\theta x}-1}{x}+(1-e^{-\theta})$, with $f(0)=0$ and $$ \frac{df}{d\theta}=(x+1)e^{\theta(x+1)}-xe^{\theta x}-2e^{\theta x}+e^{-\theta}.$$ Then let $\displaystyle g(\theta)=e^\theta \frac{df}{d\theta}=(x+1)e^{\theta(x+2)}-(x+2)e^{\theta (x+1)}+1$, with $g(0)=0$ and $$\frac{dg}{d\theta}=(x+1)(x+2)(e^{\theta(x+2)}-e^{\theta(x+1)})\geq 0.$$ Then we're done.

Clever approach - thanks!
